# Bill Amount for Tip Calc. is not influencing tip and total #'s

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

Below is my code and a picture. I have looked at previous questions regarding smilier issues but could not find help.

Furthermore, where in my code is the error in which when I enter a number in the bill field it should begins to calculate the tip amount and fill in the tip and total numbers?

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var billField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func onTap(sender: AnyObject){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func calculateTip(sender: AnyObject) {
        let tipPercentages = [0.18, 0.2, 0.25]

        let bill = Double(billField.text!)!
        let tip = bill * tipPercentages[tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
        let total = bill + tip

        tipLabel.text = String (format: "$%.2f", tip)
        totalLabel.text = String (format: "$%.2f", tip)
    }
}
```

Comment: `totalLabel.text = String (format: "$%.2f", tip)` Don't you mean `total`?

Comment: Instead of ,tip)? I have tried total. Still no go.

Comment: Does `calculateTip` even run? Can you explain what is supposed to make it run?

Comment: I would say no. The code above was typed up and created via a online tutorial from 2016 to build a simple tip calc. I guess that is the question I am looking to solve or where in my code I need to "activate" it.

Comment: Well then presumably you didn't do what the tutorial says to do, because surely in the tutorial that code _does_ run in response to some button or something in the interface that I don't see. But I can't tell you what the tutorial intended; following its instructions — or at least _thinking_ about this code and understanding it — is up to you. There's no point throwing code at us that you didn't write and don't understand, like spaghetti at a wall, and asking us to fix it.

Comment: Alright. Will use ur constructive feedback to redo it.